# How can I do a /resolve with the Soundcloud Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, soundcloud

I would like a user of my app to

1. paste in a Soundcloud track URL to a `<input>` field
2. press a submit `<button>`
3. have a function return the track's `id`

So far the only way I know how to do a `/resolve` is via command line's `curl` command as demonstrated here http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve. Is there a way to do this via a Javascript function?

e.g.

```
SC.resolve(trackURL, id, function(id, error){});
```

Answer (score 5):

All `curl` does is an HTTP request. JavaScript is definitely able to do an HTTP request, most common way of doing that is by using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest) also known as AJAX.

Popular libraries, such as jQuery simplify issuing these requests, for example:

```
// replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID with one you can get from http://soundcloud.com/you/apps
var trackUrl = 'http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic';
$.get(
  'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=' + trackUrl + '&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 
  function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
);
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/oradug/1/edit).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use SC.get() directly for almost every resources in the API (without jQuery). Like this:

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>

<script>

   SC.initialize({
       client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
   });

   SC.get("/resolve/?url=https://soundcloud.com/dogwill", {limit: 1}, function(result){
       console.log(result);
   });

</script>
```