# Need help to Modify HTML5 Audio Analyser bar graphic

Tags: javascript, html

There is a custom animated HTML audio analyzer graphic that plays an audio track and moves based on the frequencies of that audio.

This is the code from CodePen [HERE](https://codepen.io/nfj525/pen/rVBaab), I've found out that it only works on HTTPS domain only.

**Now the problem is:** I don't need to upload an audio track like what the code does, I just need a simple audio track to play automatically and removing that upload button. let's say I have a **track1.mp3** in the same directory on the server and want to play it when my HTML page is loaded.

```js
  window.onload = function() {
  var file = document.getElementById("thefile");
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

  file.onchange = function() {
    var files = this.files;
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    src.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    analyser.fftSize = 256;

    var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    console.log(bufferLength);

    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
    var barHeight;
    var x = 0;

    function renderFrame() {
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

      x = 0;

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

      ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i];

        var r = barHeight + (25 * (i / bufferLength));
        var g = 250 * (i / bufferLength);
        var b = 50;

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
        ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

        x += barWidth + 1;
      }
    }

    audio.play();
    renderFrame();
  };
};
```

```css
#thefile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

audio {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <input type="file" id="thefile" accept="audio/*" />
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: *" let's say I have a track1.mp3 in the same directory and want to play it when my page is loaded."* Let;s say is this folder on a server or your desktop?

Comment: Server with a HTTPS domain

Comment: Ok, test it out it's ready. I could only load it to a certain point because this site isn't a proper environment for [Same Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/2813224) concerns, so let me know if you run into any problems, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

## [Google Forces Yet Another Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio)

Nothing is sacred to these guys -- as of Dec 2018 New autoplay policies have been enacted upon Chrome users developing Web Audio API. If the `AudioContext();` is created *before the user interacts with a gesture* (click, tap, burp, snore, etc), the `AudioContext();` will be suspended until the user does so.

So to adjust for this engineering marvel I added a play button and wrapped everything in an eventListener.

---

### Changing `src`

> *"Now the problem is: I don't need to upload an audio track like what the code does, I just need a simple audio track to play automatically and removing that upload button. let's say I have a track1.mp3 in the same directory and want to play it when my page is loaded."*

OK, the demo has been adapted to load a normal url, you'll need to change this line so that it points to the location of the file on your server:

> ```
> audio.src = "https://host.top/path/to/file.mp3";
> ```

The new line that's above the previously mentioned line is added for [certain conflicts with CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34803952/2813224):

> ```
> audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
> ```

---

### [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/avlLKoQYzjiNMJeaNxIE/)

### Demo

**Note:** If this Stack Snippet has no sound, then go to this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/avlLKoQYzjiNMJeaNxIE/)

```js
document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', audioViz);

function audioViz(e) {

  var player = document.getElementById("player");

  player.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  player.src = "https://glsbx.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/-/dd.mp3";
  player.load();
  player.play();

  var context = new AudioContext();
  var src = context.createMediaElementSource(player);
  var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  src.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);

  analyser.fftSize = 256;

  var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  console.log(bufferLength);

  var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

  var WIDTH = canvas.width;
  var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

  var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
  var barHeight;
  var x = 0;

  function renderFrame() {

    requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

    x = 0;

    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
      barHeight = dataArray[i];

      var r = barHeight + (25 * (i / bufferLength));
      var g = 250 * (i / bufferLength);
      var b = 50;

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
      ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

      x += barWidth + 1;
    }
  }

  player.play();
  renderFrame();
}
```

```css
button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 46px;
  left: 46px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 48px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: rgba(223, 6, 39, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 128, 0.8);
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0
}

#canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#player {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<button id='load' class='load' type='button'>▶</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<audio id="player" controls>
  <source src='about:blank'>
</audio>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply... unfortunately, the code above doesn't work. here is the link where I tested it.   https://reed123.000webhostapp.com/Index.html

Comment: When I added var audio = new Audio(); it plays the audio but the bars NO... they're not there

Comment: The script already has an audio object there's no need to make another

Comment: @SaraRee There's a new policy google enacted [concerning Web Audio Dec 2018](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio), hold on...

Comment: @SaraRee Ok try now...wait...sorry.

Comment: Sorry... still I'm unable to see the bars and autoplay doesn't work too. Although I've added audio.autoplay = true; . Here is the result: https://reed123.000webhostapp.com/Index.html

Comment: You added `autoplay`? Don't add anything but the url otherwise it gets progressively more difficult to debug, There's no point in autoplay if you are required to have the user click a button or nothing happens.

Comment: Ok  @SaraRee  it works ***but remember that auto-play has been severely crippled*** in Chrome and most likely the the other browsers will follow suit if they haven't already. I posted a couple of links [concerning this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio)