# How to Fix 'images already sent in canvas but video is not playing at the end'

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in the code related to HTML and javascript. I even debug the code but still not find the error. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am using whammy API to convert images into video eg: slideshow video, delay of 3 to 5 sec depending on the user.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    var drag = document.getElementById("drag");
    var fbutton = document.getElementById("fbutton");
    var createvideo = document.getElementById("createvideo");
    var files = document.getElementById("filesinput");

    var ctx = 0;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //image to video via Whammy
    var video = new Whammy.Video(15);

    var filesarr = [];

    createvideo.addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Working... Please Wait.";

    document.getElementById('awesome').src = "";
    ctx = 0;

    canvas.width = document.getElementById("width").value;
    canvas.height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    video = new Whammy.Video(document.getElementById("framerate").value);

    //if we have images loaded
    if(filesarr.length>0){

    //loop through them and process
    for(i=0; i<filesarr.length; i++) {
    var file = filesarr[i];
    if(file.type.match(/image.*/)){
    process(file);
    } else {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "This file does not seem to be a image.";
    }
    }

    } else {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Please select some images.";
    }

    }, false);

    fbutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('filesinput').click();
    }, false);

    drag.ondragover = function(e) {e.preventDefault()}
    drag.ondrop = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    filesarr = e.dataTransfer.items;
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Please select options and click on Create Video.";
    }

    //process files VIA INPUT
    files.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    filesarr = e.target.files;
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Please select options and click on Create Video.";
    }, false);



    /* main process function */
    function process(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
    var dataUri = event.target.result;
    var img = new Image();

    //load image and drop into canvas
    img.onload = function() {

    //a custom fade in and out slideshow
    context.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    video.add(context);

    context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
    context.globalAlpha = 0.4;
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    video.add(context);

    context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
    context.globalAlpha = 0.6;
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    video.add(context);
                    context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
                    context.globalAlpha = 0.8;
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    video.add(context);                       
                    context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
                    context.globalAlpha = 1;
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                    //this should be a loop based on some user input
                    video.add(context);
                    video.add(context);
                    video.add(context);
                    video.add(context);
                    video.add(context);
                    video.add(context);
                    video.add(context);

                    context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
                    context.globalAlpha = 0.8;
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    video.add(context);
                    context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
                    context.globalAlpha = 0.6;
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    video.add(context);
                    context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
                    context.globalAlpha = 0.4;
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    video.add(context);

                    ctx++;
                    finalizeVideo();

                };
                img.src = dataUri;
            };

            reader.onerror = function(event) {
                console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }      

    function finalizeVideo(){
    if(ctx==filesarr.length){

    var start_time = +new Date;
    var output = video.compile();
    var end_time = +new Date;
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(output);

    document.getElementById('awesome').src = url; //toString converts it to a 
    URL via Object URLs, falling back to DataURL
    document.getElementById('download').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('download').href = url;
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Compiled Video in " + 
    (end_time - start_time) + "ms, file size: " + Math.ceil(output.size / 1024) 
     + "KB";
    }
    }
```

HTML PART:

```
<span id="status">Select some images.</span><br><br>


<div id="drag">DROP!
    <button type="button" id="fbutton" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Select Image(s)</button> 


    <div id="small">
        <div><label>Width:</label><input id="width" type="number" step="1" value="500"></div>
        <div><label>Height:</label><input id="height" type="number" step="1" value="300"></div>
        <div><label>Video Frame Rate:</label><input id="framerate" type="number" step="1" value="15"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="createvideo" class="btn btn-info">Create Video</button>
</div>
<input type="file" id="filesinput" multiple>

<br>
<video id="awesome" style="display:none" controls ></video>
<br>

<button type="button" style="display:none" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
id="download" download="video.webm">Download Video!</button>
<canvas id="canvas" style="display:none"></canvas>
```

the code is working fine, even when I download the video and then play, it plays perfectly but I want to play it on a chrome browser and it shows black screen.

Comment: *"...but I want to play it on a browser and not playing on the browser"*  Whah...? 

Comment: @zer00ne I want to play it on a chrome browser and it shows a black screen.

Comment: @zer00ne now i face this error :  Uncaught TypeError: URL.createeOjbectURL is not a function

Comment: You need that code refactored so that it'll play a file from an external url rather than a local file I assume. Ok, I did that for a Web Audio/Canvas demo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54151479/2813224), If it helped you resolve your issue, upvote it.